# Black screen, CPU and GPU running and fans are spinning

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, gpu

Can anyone help me detect my problem? Here are my specs:

- CPU: AMD A8-5600K
- Monitor: Asus VX239H 1080p
- Mobo: Gigabyte F2A85X-D3H
- RAM: Corsair 8GB 1600MHz
- GPU: Sapphire R9 280x Vapor-X Tri-X 3GB GDDR5
- PSU: Coolmax V-600 600W
- HDD: Seagate Barracuda 500GB

Whenever I play intense games like Tomb Raider 2013 or AC4 Black Flag, a minute or two later my CPU fans goes loud and suddenly the screen goes blank, but APU and GPU are still running. I'm starting to think that the PSU is the culprit here, because when I first bought my GPU my mobo didn't detect the new GPU.

The only time my GPU was detected was when I removed my two additional 3.5" HDDs and then voilà, my GPU is detected now. Another theory is that my APU is bottlenecking my GPU because I've never had this problem when I'm using just the APU alone for gaming. So what do you think?

Comment: This indeed sounds like a power problem

Comment: As I suspected, thank you for the confirmation. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt the problem is bottle-necking. This seems to be a common PSU problem. In my opinion, coolmax is not an entirely reliable brand.

As I can see from your PSU, it has three 12v rails (two at 18amp 1 at 15amp). You may be drawing a little too much juice from your PSU, <s>especially since low end brands have < 85% efficiency. So 600w becomes 500w or lower.</s> I would invest in a new PSU, from someone like Coolermaster or Antec.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, appreciate it. I was actually planning to buy new PSU this coming payday. Im planning on Seasonic X-850 or Seasonic P-760. Is the x-850 overkill or the P-760 is enough?

Comment: Well, for that size and price, it should be future proof. I would just go with the p-760 :)

Comment: @Mothermole1, efficiency works the other way around. The rated wattage is what it can supply internally, but the efficiency means it will draw more from the wall.

Comment: @Ash Thanks for the info! I've learned something new :)

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Thanks for your inputs. P-760 is my first choice and it's actually pricier than X-850 but not by much. Even though it has lower wattage, it is more efficient than X-850. Also, X-850 is only gold series while P-760 is platinum which accdng. to my research is better.